# How can I fix this? SassC::SyntaxError: Error: File to import not found or unreadable: tailwindcss/base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, tailwind-css

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        
remote:        Done in 346ms.
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        SassC::SyntaxError: Error: File to import not found or unreadable: tailwindcss/base.
remote:                on line 126:1 of stdin
remote:        >> @import "tailwindcss/base";
```

Comment: "Tailwind uses modern CSS features that are not recognized by the sassc-rails extension that was included by default in the Gemfile for Rails 6. In order to avoid any errors like SassC::SyntaxError, you must remove that gem from your Gemfile." https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails#conflict-with-sassc-rails

Comment: The Sassc gem uses the [C libsass compiler that was depreciated and abandoned back in 2020](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated). The only currently supported compiler is Dart-Sass - https://github.com/rails/dartsass-rails

Comment: Thank you so much, just did that, but now it shows me:  Could not detect rake tasks
 !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
 !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
 !     rake aborted!
 !     Don't know how to build task 'assets:clobber' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
 !     Did you mean?  assets:clean

Comment: I don't think you need to use the gem with tailwind though as it most likely includes the JS version of the Dart-Sass compiler in its packaged executable.

Comment: There is nothing really I or anyone else can do to help you with that error without any kind of debugging information. We would need to know what version of Rails you're using and what it is that you're actually doing when the error occured.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This question is very clear. The problem is that the CSS parser crashes on normal CSS syntax. The poster is asking how to prevent the crash.

Comment:  hi y'all. I'm getting a similar error while trying to deploy to heroku. I've updated a ton of things without deploying, so I'm not sure exactly what broke my builds yet. Seems to be related to either a sass update or a rails update. ( I went from rails 5.2 to 7.x)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Gemfile.lock whether you need [sassc](https://rubygems.org/gems/sassc) for some third party gem. If it is only define through [sass-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/sass-rails) in your Gemfile, then try to remove it. If you need some sass/scsss compiler/compressor, try to replace [sass-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/sass-rails) with [dartsass-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/dartsass-rails). This should fix it. If you have some hard dependency to [sassc](https://rubygems.org/gems/sassc) from a third party gem (check your Gemfile.lock file) read on.

If you have moved to some other asset pipe line to make tailwindcss work like [tailwindcss-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/tailwindcss-rails) and there is some other gem using it, you have to disable the rails asset pipeline use any existing CSS compressor by defining this line in your `config/application.rb`:

```
# Add this to config/application.rb to stop any css compressor
config.assets.css_compressor = nil
```

There is a detailed explanation how to figure out, where the dependency comes from and how to fix it: [Analyzing SassC::SyntaxError in Ruby on Rails 7.0](https://qameta.com/posts/analyzing-sassc-syntax-error-in-ruby-on-rails-7-0/)